# Bootstrap Grid Layout show ComboBox on Extra Small instead of multiple buttons

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use best practice when designing my application so instead of 'hacking' together something I'm after some advice to start.

I'm using Bootstrap 4.1.3 in my Angular App.

Basically I want my application to show many (8+) buttons across the page when in Extra Large (i.e Desktop) but when in Extra Small (i.e Mobile) I don't want the buttons to just show vertically. I'd like in smaller formats to be able to replace the buttons with a dropdown for ease of use.

Here is my starting code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Test Button 1</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Test Button 2</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Test Button 3</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Test Button 4</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Test Button 5</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Test Button 6</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">Test Button 7</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is what the result is:

[Extra Large Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5KjO.png)

[Extra Small Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzE7v.png)

As mentioned above, I would like the Extra Small format to no longer show the buttons (because they will get vertically stacked and it is messy), but I've read that using Bootstrap Display Utility is not the best due to doubling up of code etc?

Any thoughts on how to achieve this?

Comment: Maybe you could use [navbar](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/) with navbar-collapse? Then you won't need to double up on code.

Comment: I already have a navbar on my page. I did think about using that, but again thought it was a bit silly and there must be a better way. Is there any major issues using display other than doubling up on code?

Comment: Navbar takes you 80% on the way, if you apply some custom styles to it (list items styled as buttons on desktop). We have taken the shortcut like you mention, by showing a `select` element on mobile, and buttons on desktop. I can't come up with a reason why you shouldn't do it like that other than what you pointed out yourself. If it solves your problem, go with the display toggling.